# Cannot Add the number of repeats to RegExp JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, sorting

I've wrote the code for calculation the repeatable symbol maximal substring length using RegExp. For finish I need to include to constructor the numbers of repeats:

```js
const word = "fkffhjhlkjhkjhkjhqqqhqkqkqkhk";
const toCharWord = Array.from(word);
const uniqueChars = new Set(toCharWord);
console.log(uniqueChars);



let lenghtsArrays = [];
for (let element of uniqueChars) {
  const regExp = new RegExp(`${element}{2,}`, "g"); // Something wrong here!!!
  lenghtsArrays.push(word.match(regExp).length);


}
console.log(lenghtsArrays);

function getMaxOfArray(numArray) {
  return Math.max.apply(null, numArray);
}
console.log(getMaxOfArray(lenghtsArrays));
```

How I should to write this line correct? Thanks in advance!

Comment: _"Something wrong here"_ What is it? Your RegExp compiles successfully. It throws on `word.match(regExp).length` though because (obviously), `.match()` is not guaranteed to return a match and therefore calling `.length` on null will fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Troubleshooted!
Decision was in separating methods of matching symbol in the word from length's matched arrays definition. Was used additional array in program.
Fixed code here:

```
const word = "fddfddssrfeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeffrsdffuuuuuuuuiiiiingfggggggivdf";
const toCharWord = Array.from(word);
const uniqueChars = new Set(toCharWord);
const numberOfRepeats = 2;

let lengthsArrays = [];

for (let element of uniqueChars){
const regExp = new RegExp(`${element}{${numberOfRepeats},}`,"g");

lengthsArrays.push(word.match(regExp));
}

let array = [];

lengthsArrays.forEach((data) => {
if (data !== null && data !== undefined) {
    data.forEach((arr) => {
            array.push(Array.from(arr).length);
     });
   }
});

function getMaxOfArray(numArray) {

return Math.max.apply(null, numArray);
}
if(getMaxOfArray(array)<0){
console.log(`No repeatable symbols with number of repeats = 
${numberOfRepeats}`);
}else {
    console.log(getMaxOfArray(array));
}
```

Comment: Please try to give proper explanation of the answer.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: Yes,sure! I've added expanded comment in description.

Answer (score 2):

Your code throws an exception specifically when coming upon the case of `h`. Since there isn't any match in `word` for the RegExp pattern `/h{2,}/g`, [`String.prototype.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) returns `null`. `null` doesn't have a `length` property, which is why you're seeing this error.

You can solve this simply by making the result of `word.match(regExp)` [optionally chained (`?.`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining), which will gracefully handle such a condition (albeit returning `undefined` instead of a numeric value):

```js
const word = "fkffhjhlkjhkjhkjhqqqhqkqkqkhk";
const toCharWord = Array.from(word);
const uniqueChars = new Set(toCharWord);
console.log(uniqueChars);

let lenghtsArrays = [];
for (let element of uniqueChars) {
  const regExp = new RegExp(`${element}{2,}`, "g"); // Something wrong here!!!
  lenghtsArrays.push(word.match(regExp)?.length);
}
console.log(lenghtsArrays);

function getMaxOfArray(numArray) {
  return Math.max.apply(null, numArray);
}
console.log(getMaxOfArray(lenghtsArrays));
```

Going a step further, you could use the [nullish coalescing operator (`??`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) to return a value of `0` in these cases:

```js
const word = "fkffhjhlkjhkjhkjhqqqhqkqkqkhk";
const toCharWord = Array.from(word);
const uniqueChars = new Set(toCharWord);
console.log(uniqueChars);

let lenghtsArrays = [];
for (let element of uniqueChars) {
  const regExp = new RegExp(`${element}{2,}`, "g"); // Something wrong here!!!
  lenghtsArrays.push(word.match(regExp)?.length ?? 0);
}
console.log(lenghtsArrays);

function getMaxOfArray(numArray) {
  return Math.max.apply(null, numArray);
}
console.log(getMaxOfArray(lenghtsArrays));
```

Comment: Maybe `word.match(regExp)?.length ?? 0` to give a more intuitive result?

Comment: @41686d6564 Read my mind! Just edited that advice into my answer.

Comment: Great, thanks for updating :) Just nitpicking: I'd advise against using `||` for this purpose (especially for beginners) because although it will work perfectly fine in this particular case, it might come to bite them later. E.g., `match?.length || -1` will return `-1` if the length is zero while `match?.length ?? -1` will _only_ return `-1` if `match` is null.

Comment: @41686d6564 Good point - a small gap in my knowledge there. I initially had thought to use `??` (as my own personal preference) but recalled that its in-browser support is at about [89% globally](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_operators_logical_nullish_assignment) (which, while small, some people with odd target audiences may balk at). Nevertheless I agree with the sentiment that it is a technically more preferable method and will update the answer as such. Appreciate the nitpick wholeheartedly!

Comment: Thanks you, guys, for take care about! Unfortunately, it still doesn't work correct. I want to clarify one detail: if I don't use the repeatable pattern in my code `...{2,}' or I dont use variable `${element}...` in it work correct(but it doesn't compliance with technical task). Maybe something wrong with syntax? I try to use different scenarios, but unsuccessfully...